# getting store attr in a route emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm fetching a user using:

`var user  = this.store.find('user', user_id);`

here is the user model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  is_admin: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

im trying to run a before model where i check if the user is an admin and then do something if its true or false, example:

```
beforeModel: function(){
    var user  = this.store.find('user', 1);

    if(user.get('is_admin')){
        return 'do something since they are an admin';
    }
},
```

I also tried doing this instead:

```
beforeModel: function(){
    var user  = this.store.find('user', 1);

    return user.then(function(response){
        if(response.is_admin){
            return 'do something since they are an admin';
        }
    });
},
```

How can I get that `is_admin` attribute in a route?

Answer (score 0):

You could define `isAdmin` property in your route, and set it when `user` promise resolved.

```
//route
isAdmin: false,
beforeModel: function() {
  var self = this; 
  return this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user){
    self.set('isAdmin', user.get('is_admin'));
  }, function(){
    // on reject
  })
}
```